# How do I rewrite URL using .htacess without consequences for $_GET data

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, get

I would like to change my URL with some $_GET data such as:

```
http://www.website.com/articles.php?article=article_title_stored_in_database
http://www.website.com/simple_page.php?page=page_title_stored_in_database
```

and make them look like this:

```
http://www.website.com/articles/article_title_stored_in_database/
http://www.website.com/pages/page_title_stored_in_database/
```

Another Q: If I change URL that had $_GET data inside, will it be possible to access them after the change? So if the adress will be:

```
http://www.website.com/articles/article_title_stored_in_database/
```

variable $_GET['article'] will return 'article_title_stored_in_database' ?
Thank you.

Comment: Same URL structure cannot be forwarded to 2 different PHP files at the same time

Comment: Does it mean that folder "content" can be used only for articles.php OR simple_page.php ?

Comment: You can use 2 different prefixes for 2 different php files and `/content` doesn't have to be a real folder.

Comment: **Thank you.** I edited the question

Comment: I posted an answer below after your edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ simple_page.php?article=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. .htaccess file is alien technology for my understanding. I hope it works fine. It doesnt works on my Xampp Apache server even if I have AllowOverride set to All. but I believe it'll work well on hostinig. Thanks a lot again, for your help! :)

Comment: It does not. I think its a xampp problem. I have many problems with xampp right now, e.g., method POST doesnt work. If I send something with post method, variable(array) $_POST is empty, and many many other problems. Right now I am looking for different program to use.

Comment: I've tested with XAMPP and it worked. Make sure you have only these 2 rules in your .htaccess and there is no other .htaccess in your system

Comment: When I try to reach /clanky/nadpis_clanku .. 404 error

Comment: Why do you have `/1/` before `clanky` in URL? Should it not be `domain.com/clanky/nadpis_clanku`?

Comment: I got my entire project in folder /1, so it is a document root. (xampp/htdocs/1/FILES)

Comment: But I don't see `/files/` in your URL. I suggest you spend some time reading .htaccess [start with this tutorial](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: I uninstalled Xampp and installed Wamp instead. Coppied files and database. Method POST works and your RewriteRule as well. Maybe Xampp wasnt installed correctly.. anyway, everything works great and thank you for your help and your patience with newbie like me. :)